# Is it possible navigate to a certain screen after open a push notification toast on windows phone app?

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, ibm-mobilefirst

I´m doing an app with push notifications on MFP 7 and I want to open certain screen with specific information after tap on the toast push notification, I have found some information but I don´t know how to pass the parameters of screen and others that i need. I´m using an http adapter to send the notifications

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Event source notifications then you could send a specialized parameter as the payload and check for its value as the app is loading (or when the push is displayed, doesn't matter). Then, change to a specific page content based on the payload value.

For example, here I'm sending the payload as "foo" with value "bar":

```
WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, { 
    badge: 1, 
    sound: "sound.mp3", 
    activateButtonLabel: "ClickMe", 
    alert: notificationText, 
    payload: { 
        foo : 'bar' 
    } 
});
```

And in the app logic I check for the value:

```
function pushNotificationReceived(props, payload) {     
    if (payload.foo == "bar") { 
        // change page, etc and display the message
    }   
}
```

You can also use Tag-based notifications (in case the information sent via push notifications is not sensitive information) and then act based on the tag. You can read more about tag notifications in the Developer Center: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/notifications/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MPNS notifications and query is about Windows Phone silverlight (hybrid), to navigate to specific page when a toast notification arrives, first you will need to specify the page and other details in "param" of MPNS toast.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html%23notifyAllDevices

Refer specifically to the notification options under MPNS -> Toast

Eg:

```
var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit,{custom : 'data'});

notification.MPNS.toast={text1 : "hello" , text2 :"world",param:"/MainPage.xaml?value1=54321"};

WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notification);
```

To retrieve the value received (in this example, 54321) , to the best of my understanding there is no straight way. You can write a Cordova plugin 
that can retrieve the value and use it to obtain the value assigned to the key "value1" in the example.